# PHP Mysql insert if exist modify field

Tags: php, mysql

so my actual code is:

```
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($array); $i++) {
    if ($array[$i]) {
        mysql_query("   INSERT INTO guest(nomeconv)
            VALUES(
            '".$array[$i]."',
        )");
    }
}
```

but i want if the value of $array[$i] already exists in table, i want to add $array[$i]." 1".

for example if the value i want to insert was "John" if already exists i want to preserve the actual value and the new one must be "John 1".

How can i do that?

Comment: You can select the said value first and if you have 0 result then insert

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

Comment: And if you are trying to insert John 1 and it already exist, what could be the value ?

Comment: Shafeeq if exists the value then we must insert John 2, or John 3 if the previous exists

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) will help you avoid making mistakes like this.